# mysql create procedure syntax issue line 1

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax-error

I get a syntax error on line 1 of the following procedure:

```
DELIMITER | 
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_autocallFillCallQueue
BEGIN 
    DECLARE maxCalls TINYINT(1);
    SELECT autocall_maxCalls INTO maxCalls FROM `options` LIMIT 0,1;

    REPEAT

        INSERT INTO `callQueue` (`phoneNumber`, 'waiting') 
        SELECT `phoneNumber` FROM `phoneNumbers` WHERE `accessRestriction` != 'blacklist' && `flagAutocall` = 1;

        SET maxCalls = maxCalls - 1;

        UNTIL maxCalls = 0
    END REPEAT;         

END;
|
```

I am setting the delimiter before and after this. I have a feeling it is something silly (as this is my first mysql stored proc). I'm totally stumped atm though.

FYI, this is the error:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'PROCEDURE sp_autocallFillCallQueue
BEGIN
DECLARE @maxCalls TINYINT(1);
SELECT ' at line 1
```

Comment: SOLVED: error was user. I have version 4.1 and stored procs became available in 5.0.

Answer (score 0):

In order to remove this from the "unanswered" list...

Prediction: You are using version 4.1, but stored procedures didn't become available until version 5.0.

Problem solved!