# Mysql stored procedure syntax

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, syntax

I am trying to write simple mysql stored procedure and it seems that I can't get it right, so far I have

```
    delimiter //
    create procedure addRecord(_login varchar(15),_artist varchar(50),_record varchar(50))
    begin
    declare dbArtist varchar(50);
    delcare dbRecord varchar(50);

    set dbArtist = (select artistname from artists where lower(artistname) = lower(_artist));

    set dbRecord=(select recordname from records where lower(recordname)=lower(_record));
    if not exists (select * from Artists where lower(artistname)=lower(_artist)) then
    begin
      INSERT INTO `Artists`(`ArtistName`) VALUES (_artist);
      set dbArtist=_artist;
    end

    if not exists (select * from Records as R inner join Artists as A on R.ArtistId=A.ArtistId where lower(R.RecordName)=lower(_record) and A.ArtistName=dbArtist) then
    begin
      INSERT INTO `Records`(`ArtistId`, `RecordName`) VALUES ((select artistid from artists where artistname=dbArtist),_record);
      set dbRecord=_record;
    end

    end
```

but I get syntax error in line 4:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds 
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'dbRecord varchar(50);
set dbArtist = (select artistname from artists where lowe' at line 4
```

this message error was returned to me by phpMyAdmin, can anyone tell me why do I get an error?

edit: modified version, still not good

```
delimiter //
create procedure addRecord(_login varchar(15),_artist varchar(50),_record varchar(50))
begin
declare dbArtist varchar(50);
declare dbRecord varchar(50);

set dbArtist = (select artistname from artists where lower(artistname) = lower(_artist));
set dbRecord=(select recordname from records where lower(recordname)=lower(_record));
if not exists (select * from Artists where lower(artistname)=lower(_artist)) then
begin
  INSERT INTO `Artists`(`ArtistName`) VALUES (_artist);
  set dbArtist=_artist;
end

if not exists 
(select * from Records as R inner join Artists as A on R.ArtistId = A.ArtistId where     lower(R.RecordName)=lower(_record) and A.ArtistName=dbArtist) 
then
begin
  INSERT INTO `Records`(`ArtistId`, `RecordName`) VALUES ( (select artistid from artists where artistname=dbArtist) ,_record);
  set dbRecord=_record;
end

end
```

now error in line 14 and message:

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to    your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if not exists (select * from Records as R inner join Artists as A on R.ArtistId' at line 14
```

Comment: i hope you are using new version .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3356929/mysql-create-procedure-syntax-issue-line-1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you misspelled `DECLARE`:

```
delcare dbRecord varchar(50);
```

UPDATE: For your next error, the problem is your illegal use of `NOT EXISTS`.

Within a stored procedure the proper approach is to count the existing rows, and then conditionally insert a value if the count is 0.

Something like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
INTO @v_row_count
FROM Artists 
WHERE LOWER(artistname)=LOWER(_artist);

IF (@v_row_count = 0)
THEN
  INSERT INTO `Artists`(`ArtistName`) VALUES (_artist);
  set dbArtist=_artist;
END IF;
```

P.S. To avoid poor performance on on your select query, you should consider using a collation that is not case-sensitive so you don't need to apply the `LOWER()` function to the artistname column.

Comment: I spelled corectly now declare but this time I get error in line 14

Comment: Your usage of `NOT EXISTS` is not supported. See my updated answer.

Comment: Ok, now it works. I didn't even fought that this usage is not supported, earlier I used mssql and there it is legal to use not exists in such way. Thanks.